# Boost::Asio - get_io_service exception thrown

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Can anyone explain to me why when I want to call get_io_service() I get the following exception?

[image]

I see that at startup acceptor is initialized but when client wants to connect and server wants to open new connection then acceptor has some random numbers. I don't know why this is happening.

My code:

main.cpp

```
#include "TServer.h"
#include "TDatabase.h"
#include "Includes.h"
#include "Structures.h"

int main()
{
try
{
    std::cout << "========================================" << std::endl
        << "= Game Server v1.0 by Gravity1        =" << std::endl
        << "========================================" << std::endl;

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    Database database;
    std::vector<std::vector<TServer>> Server;
    srand(time(0));

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini("game_server_config.ini", pt);

    database.host = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.HOST");
    database.username = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.USER");
    database.password = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.PASS");
    database.schema = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.SCHEMA");

    std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> Database_ptr = std::make_shared<TDatabase>(database);

    Database_ptr->Connect();

    short server_count = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_COUNT");

    if (server_count > 0)
        Server.resize(server_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < server_count; i++)
    {
        short channel_count = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL_COUNT");

        for (int j = 0; j < channel_count; j++)
        {
            Canal CanalTemp;
            CanalTemp.ip = pt.get<std::string>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL" + std::to_string(j + 1) + "_IP");
            CanalTemp.port = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL" + std::to_string(j + 1) + "_PORT");
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(CanalTemp.ip), CanalTemp.port);
            Server[i].emplace_back(io_service, Database_ptr,endpoint);
        }
    }

    io_service.run();
}

catch (std::exception &e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

std::cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

TServer.cpp

```
TServer::TServer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service,std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> database, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint &endpoint) :
acceptor(io_service,endpoint)
{
Accept_Connection();
}

void TServer::Accept_Connection()
{
Connection = std::make_shared<TSession>(acceptor.get_io_service(),Database);
acceptor.async_accept(*(Connection->Socket()),(boost::bind(&TServer::Handle_Connection, this, Connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error)));
}

void TServer::Handle_Connection(std::shared_ptr<TSession> Connection, const boost::system::error_code &error)
{
if (!error)
{
    Connection->Start();
    Accept_Connection();
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to call `acceptor.listen()` ?

Comment: https://www.livecoding.tv/sehe/ ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple.

You're emplacing `TServer`s to the back of a vector. When you do, it will (may) reallocate, invalidating the references that are held in other parts of your program. See [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

In your case, such a reference is immediately held, because `Accept_Connection()` is called from within the constructor and it **bind**s to the `this` pointer. Remember, the `this` pointer points to the *address of a `TServer` element inside the vector*.

OOPS. When your completion handler fires, the element is/may have been reallocated. So the pointer is simply dangling and you have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can fix it in different ways:

1. replace the vectors with a container that guarantees stability of reference on insertion. For example, you can just use a `list<>` instead:

   ```
   std::list<std::list<TServer> > servers;
   if (server_count > 0)
       servers.resize(server_count);

   auto current_server = servers.begin();

   for (int i = 0; i < server_count; i++, ++current_server) {
       short channel_count = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL_COUNT");

       for (int j = 0; j < channel_count; j++) {
           Canal CanalTemp;
           CanalTemp.ip   = pt.get<std::string>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL" + std::to_string(j + 1) + "_IP");
           CanalTemp.port = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_"       + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL" + std::to_string(j + 1) + "_PORT");
           tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(CanalTemp.ip), CanalTemp.port);

           current_server->emplace_back(io_service, Database_ptr, endpoint);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can postpone the initial bind until *after* all the channels were added to all servers:

   ```
   TServer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> database, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint &endpoint)
           : acceptor(io_service, endpoint), database(database)
   {
       //Accept_Connection();
   }
   ```

   And do that explicitly before `io_service::run()`:

   ```
   for(auto& server: servers)
       for(auto& channel: server)
           channel.Accept_Connection();

   io_service.run();
   ```

   > **Note:** In fact, in idiomatic Asio code, running asynchronous operations directly from within a constructor is frequently *not possible*. Look e.g. at the `TSession` type; it couldn't bind a completion handler to a member function because `shared_from_this()` is **not allowed** from within the constructor (["*Note that prior to calling `shared_from_this` on an object `t`, there must be a `shared_ptr` that owns `t`.*"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)).

Both work. I opt for the first here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45486ee3afc69996)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
// for iterator and reference stability (see:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)
#include <list> 

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct Canal {
    std::string ip;
    int port;
};

struct Database {
    std::string host, username, password, schema;
};

struct TDatabase {
    TDatabase(Database config) : details(config) {}

    void Connect() {
        std::cout 
            << "Connecting to fake database " << details.host << "/" << details.schema
            << " with user " << details.username << " and password '" << std::string(details.password.size(), '*') << "'\n";
    }
  private:
    Database details;
};

struct TSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<TSession> {
    TSession(boost::asio::io_service& svc, std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> db) :
        _svc(svc), _socket(_svc), _db(db) {}

    tcp::socket& Socket() { return _socket; }

    void Start() {
        boost::asio::async_read(_socket, _sb, 
                boost::bind(&TSession::HandleReceived, shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    } 

    void HandleReceived(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!ec || boost::asio::error::eof == ec) {
            std::cout << "Received from " << _socket.remote_endpoint() << ": '" << &_sb << "'\n";
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "Error reading from peer: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::io_service& _svc;
    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> _db;
    boost::asio::streambuf _sb;
};

struct TServer {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> database;

    TServer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> database, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint &endpoint)
            : acceptor(io_service, endpoint), database(database)
    {
        Accept_Connection();
    }

    void Accept_Connection() {
        auto Connection = std::make_shared<TSession>(acceptor.get_io_service(), database);
        acceptor.async_accept(Connection->Socket(),
                boost::bind(&TServer::Handle_Connection, this, Connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void Handle_Connection(std::shared_ptr<TSession> Connection, const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            Connection->Start();
            Accept_Connection();
        } else
            std::cout << "Error: " << error.message() << "\n";
    }
};

//#include "TServer.h"
//#include "TDatabase.h"
//#include "Includes.h"
//#include "Structures.h"
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "========================================" << std::endl
                  << "= Game Server v1.0 by Gravity1        =" << std::endl
                  << "========================================" << std::endl;

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        Database database;
        std::list<std::list<TServer> > servers;
        srand(time(0));

        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_ini("game_server_config.ini", pt);

        database.host     = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.HOST");
        database.username = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.USER");
        database.password = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.PASS");
        database.schema   = pt.get<std::string>("DATABASE.SCHEMA");

        std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> Database_ptr = std::make_shared<TDatabase>(database);
        Database_ptr->Connect();

        short server_count = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_COUNT");

        if (server_count > 0)
            servers.resize(server_count);

        auto current_server = servers.begin();

        for (int i = 0; i < server_count; i++, ++current_server) {
            short channel_count = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL_COUNT");

            for (int j = 0; j < channel_count; j++) {
                Canal CanalTemp;
                CanalTemp.ip   = pt.get<std::string>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_" + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL" + std::to_string(j + 1) + "_IP");
                CanalTemp.port = pt.get<short>("GAME_SERVER.SERVER_"       + std::to_string(i + 1) + "_CHANNEL" + std::to_string(j + 1) + "_PORT");
                tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(CanalTemp.ip), CanalTemp.port);

                current_server->emplace_back(io_service, Database_ptr, endpoint);
            }
        }

        io_service.run();
    } 
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I used a configuration of

```
[DATABASE]
HOST=localhost
USER=root
PASS=youbet
SCHEMA=my_game

[GAME_SERVER]
SERVER_COUNT=1
SERVER_1_CHANNEL_COUNT=2
SERVER_1_CHANNEL1_IP=127.0.0.1
SERVER_1_CHANNEL1_PORT=6767
SERVER_1_CHANNEL2_IP=127.0.0.2
SERVER_1_CHANNEL2_PORT=6868
```

Which, when running clients on both channels (port 6767 and 6868) prints an "endless" repeat of:

```
========================================
= Game Server v1.0 by Gravity1        =
========================================
Connecting to fake database localhost/my_game with user root and password '******'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54942: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37217: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54945: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37220: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54947: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37222: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54949: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37224: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54951: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37226: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54953: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37228: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54955: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37230: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:54957: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37232: 'hello OTHER channel
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely unrelated, but your configuration format really **begs** for a *hierarchical* format like JSON or XML.

For fun, I refactored that sample to use XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CONFIG>
  <DATABASE>
    <HOST>localhost</HOST>
    <USER>root</USER>
    <PASS>youbet</PASS>
    <SCHEMA>my_game</SCHEMA>
  </DATABASE>
  <GAME_SERVER>
    <SERVER>
      <CHANNEL>
        <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
        <PORT>6767</PORT>
      </CHANNEL>
      <CHANNEL>
        <IP>127.0.0.2</IP>
        <PORT>6868</PORT>
      </CHANNEL>
    </SERVER>
  </GAME_SERVER>
</CONFIG>
```

Which you can read with the following snippets:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::read_xml("game_server_config.xml", pt);

if (auto dbconfig = pt.get_child_optional("CONFIG.DATABASE")) {
    database.host     = dbconfig->get<std::string>("HOST");
    database.username = dbconfig->get<std::string>("USER");
    database.password = dbconfig->get<std::string>("PASS");
    database.schema   = dbconfig->get<std::string>("SCHEMA");
}
```

And for the server/channels:

```
for (auto& serverconfig: pt.get_child("CONFIG.GAME_SERVER")) {
    if ("SERVER" != serverconfig.first)
        continue;

    servers.emplace_back();
    auto& current_server = servers.back();

    for (auto& channelconfig: serverconfig.second) {
        if ("CHANNEL" != channelconfig.first)
            continue;

        Canal CanalTemp;
        CanalTemp.ip   = channelconfig.second.get<std::string>("IP");
        CanalTemp.port = channelconfig.second.get<short>("PORT");
        tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(CanalTemp.ip), CanalTemp.port);

        current_server.emplace_back(io_service, Database_ptr, endpoint);
    }
}
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b09f4d1ef2f4c4e)</kbd>** as well :)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
// for iterator and reference stability (see:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)
#include <list> 

using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

struct Canal {
    std::string ip;
    int port;
};

struct Database {
    std::string host, username, password, schema;
};

struct TDatabase {
    TDatabase(Database config) : details(config) {}

    void Connect() {
        std::cout 
            << "Connecting to fake database " << details.host << "/" << details.schema
            << " with user " << details.username << " and password '" << std::string(details.password.size(), '*') << "'\n";
    }
  private:
    Database details;
};

struct TSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<TSession> {
    TSession(boost::asio::io_service& svc, std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> db) :
        _svc(svc), _socket(_svc), _db(db) {}

    tcp::socket& Socket() { return _socket; }

    void Start() {
        boost::asio::async_read(_socket, _sb, 
                boost::bind(&TSession::HandleReceived, shared_from_this(),
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    } 

    void HandleReceived(boost::system::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!ec || boost::asio::error::eof == ec) {
            std::cout << "Received from " << _socket.remote_endpoint() << ": '" << &_sb << "'\n";
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "Error reading from peer: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

  private:
    boost::asio::io_service& _svc;
    tcp::socket _socket;
    std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> _db;
    boost::asio::streambuf _sb;
};

struct TServer {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> database;

    TServer(boost::asio::io_service &io_service, std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> database, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint &endpoint)
            : acceptor(io_service, endpoint), database(database)
    {
        Accept_Connection();
    }

    void Accept_Connection() {
        auto Connection = std::make_shared<TSession>(acceptor.get_io_service(), database);
        acceptor.async_accept(Connection->Socket(),
                boost::bind(&TServer::Handle_Connection, this, Connection, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void Handle_Connection(std::shared_ptr<TSession> Connection, const boost::system::error_code &error) {
        if (!error) {
            Connection->Start();
            Accept_Connection();
        } else
            std::cout << "Error: " << error.message() << "\n";
    }
};

//#include "TServer.h"
//#include "TDatabase.h"
//#include "Includes.h"
//#include "Structures.h"
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main() {
    try {
        std::cout << "========================================" << std::endl
                  << "= Game Server v1.0 by Gravity1        =" << std::endl
                  << "========================================" << std::endl;

        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        Database database;
        std::list<std::list<TServer> > servers;
        srand(time(0));

        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        boost::property_tree::read_xml("game_server_config.xml", pt);

        if (auto dbconfig = pt.get_child_optional("CONFIG.DATABASE")) {
            database.host     = dbconfig->get<std::string>("HOST");
            database.username = dbconfig->get<std::string>("USER");
            database.password = dbconfig->get<std::string>("PASS");
            database.schema   = dbconfig->get<std::string>("SCHEMA");
        }

        std::shared_ptr<TDatabase> Database_ptr = std::make_shared<TDatabase>(database);
        Database_ptr->Connect();

        for (auto& serverconfig: pt.get_child("CONFIG.GAME_SERVER")) {
            if ("SERVER" != serverconfig.first)
                continue;

            servers.emplace_back();
            auto& current_server = servers.back();

            for (auto& channelconfig: serverconfig.second) {
                if ("CHANNEL" != channelconfig.first)
                    continue;

                Canal CanalTemp;
                CanalTemp.ip   = channelconfig.second.get<std::string>("IP");
                CanalTemp.port = channelconfig.second.get<short>("PORT");
                tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(CanalTemp.ip), CanalTemp.port);

                current_server.emplace_back(io_service, Database_ptr, endpoint);
            }
        }

        io_service.run();
    } 
    catch (std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Prints

```
========================================
= Game Server v1.0 by Gravity1        =
========================================
Connecting to fake database localhost/my_game with user root and password '******'
Received from 127.0.0.1:55712: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37987: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:55714: 'hello channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:37989: 'hello OTHER channel
'
Received from 127.0.0.1:55716: 'hello channel
'
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks . It works perfectly now ! Again thanks for help ;).